# FCM push notification getting invalid registration using node js Duplicate

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing REST API using node js and there is a rest endpoint to send firebase push notification.I'm getting issue sending push notification to android

My error code is :

```
{"multicast_id":6890655614582327866,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

My code is below:

```
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
    var serverKey = 'AAAAXOrkfxk:....cii'; 
    var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);
    var message = { 
        to: '55fc64...21d',     
        notification: {
            title: 'Title of push notification', 
            body: 'Body of push notification' 
        },
        data: {  
            my_key: 'my value',
            my_another_key: 'my another value'
        }
    };
    fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        }
    });
```

Getting token id from android and run it with postman but always it gives error like Invalid Registration.
Kindly help anyone.

Comment: I believe the device you are pushing the notification to is not registered on the firebase account or probably is deregistered. Best will be to login to firebase account and get the registered device id from there.

Comment: @Don I already registered My Project in Firebase Account, for example, if I tried cloud messaging in firebase account for test message notifications it's receiving in mobile, but while I pushing via in Node JS showing above kindly help me out from this issues

Comment: Then probably there is a problem with the `server-key` try using the other key, there are two one `server-key` other `server app key`